# Two column webpage, menu loading seperate HTML files with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

It sounds so simple but none of what I could find on google worked so far. I've found a similar question on here with a solution that looks exactly like what I'm looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/sJ6Bj/4/

Here's the HTML:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Two-pane navigation</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="navigation">
                <h1>Navigation</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#page1" class="page-link">Page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page2" class="page-link">Page 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="pages">
                <div id="page1" class="page">
                    <h1>Page 1</h1>
                    <p>This is all the lovely content on page 1.</p>
                    <p>Let's add a bunch of stuff to make it scroll.</p>
                    <p style="font-size: 72px">.<br/>.<br/>.<br/>.<br/>.<br/>.</p>
                    <p>This is at the bottom of the page.</p>
                </div>

                <div id="page2" class="page">
                    <h1>Page 2</h1>
                    <p>This is all the lovely content on page 2.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

JavaScript (assumes JQuery is loaded):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".page-link").on("click", function(e) {
        $(".page").fadeOut(250);
        setTimeout(function() { $($(e.currentTarget).attr("href")).fadeIn(250); }, 250);
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#navigation {
    position: fixed;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

#pages {
    margin-left: 270px; /* 250px + 20px of actual margin */
}

.page {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

The only problem is, I want to load different Youtube videos with autoplay. Which means that with the given example you already hear all of the audio play in the back. To make sure this doesnt happen I want to load different, seperate html files containing the youtube videos.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should load your pages via AJAX. That would solve the problem of Youtube content playing in the background. And drastically reduce initial page load time.

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Two-pane navigation</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="navigation">
                <h1>Navigation</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="page-1.html" class="page-link">Page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page-2.html" class="page-link">Page 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="pages">
                <!-- ajax content loads here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript/jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".page-link").on("click", function(e) {
        $.get($(this).attr('href'))
        .done(function(data) {
            $('#pages').html(data);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanx for your response. Where would I locate the content? In seperate files or not. It's not clear for me how to link to a seperate .html and make it appear in the "pages" div.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Now you can retrieve static html files using this code. The html files should only have content that normally sits between the <body> tags. This is because the page you are loading into already has html, head & body tags. For example, you could have this in your static html files:

<div>I am content that will appear in the main page when called via ajax.</div>

Comment: The problem I keep having is that it just opens the link as a new page instead of it appearing inside of the "pages" div.